# Difference in the way of accessing form-controls

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formbuilder, form-control

I have started learning angular and working on my pet project, My form in angular is defined as this

```
      this.symptomForm = this.fb.group({
        symptoms: this.fb.array(this.createArray()),
        sNames: this.fb.array([this.createSnameFormGroup()])
      });
```

and template is as follows

```
<form [formGroup]="symptomForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div>
        <div formArrayName="symptoms">
          <div *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms.controls; let i=index" class="symptomsName">
            <span class="button3">{{symptom.value}}</span>
            <span class="buttonDelete" (click)="removeSymptom(i)" >X</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="sNames">
            <div *ngFor="let name of symptomForm.get('sNames')['controls']; let i = index" >
                <div formGroupName="{{i}}" class="symptomsInput">
                <p>Enter New Symptom</p>
                <div class="newSymptomContainer">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="sName" class="form-control symptomInputBox" >
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px;"><span class="buttonAdd" (click)="addSymptom()" >+</span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> &nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

I am able to loop through/render symptoms using `*ngFor="let symptom of symptoms.controls; let i=index"`

but when I do same for sNames like `*ngFor="let symptom of sNames.controls; let i=index"` I get an error saying

> Property 'sNames' does not exist on type
> 'SymptomComposerFormComponent'.

so I tried this after searching through web and this worked `*ngFor="let name of symptomForm.get('sNames')['controls'];`

but I am curious why its not working as same as symptoms ? why it works with `.get` ?

**Update**
other info

```
      createArray() {
        let formArray = [];
        for(var i =0; i< this.symptomsData.length; i++) {
          //console.log('asdf ; ', this.symptomsData[i])
          formArray.push(new FormControl(this.symptomsData[i]['value']));
        }
        return formArray;
      }

      createSnameFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({
          'sName': new FormControl('')
        })
      }
```

Any help in clearing the doubt is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put it in a stackblitz?

Comment: I think `controls` is an object, not an array

Comment: @MikeS. updated question with other info.